# Maya Python - Using data from UI

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I am working on a scripting program and struggling a bit with the UI. I've made a couple of UIs, all of which seem to work fine individually, but I don't know how to use the data inputted in a UI to another function. I'm trying to get the Gun Type (selected by the user in `Bullet_Spray_Generator`) to then affect which of the UIs is then called. Each Gun Type requires a different set of values for the sliders, so I made a different UI for each. I think I need to pass the data selected from the BSG into an `if` function in order to call the correct (second) UI, but running it just always jumps to the `else` function and closes the window. Here's my code so far:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial


if (cmds.window("Bullet_Spray_Generator", exists = True)): 
    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")
if (cmds.window("BSG2", exists = True)): 
    cmds.deleteUI("BSG2")

cmds.select(all=True)
cmds.delete()



def goShoot(numOfShots, distToTarget, *pArgs): 
    print "Begin"
    cmds.deleteUI("BSG2")
    createWall()

def cancelShoot(*pArgs):
    print "cancel"
    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")


def createWall():
    cmds.select(all=True)
    cmds.delete()
    wall = cmds.polyCube(h=10, w=15, d=1, name='wall')
    cmds.move(0,5,0, 'wall')


def createGunUI(gunType, *pArgs):
    if (GunSelectCtrl == 'Pistol'):
        createPistolUI()
    elif (GunSelectCtrl == 'Shotgun'):
        createShotgunUI()
    elif (GunSelectCtrl == 'SMG'):
        createSMGUI()
    elif (GunSelectCtrl == 'Sniper Rifle'):
        createSniperUI()
    elif (GunSelectCtrl == 'RPG'):
        createRPGUI()
    else:
        print "Something went wrong"
        cancelShoot()



def createPistolUI():
    cmds.window("Pistol")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=9, value=4, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("Pistol")

def createShotgunUI():
    cmds.window("Shotgun")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=4, value=2, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("Shotgun")

def createSMGUI():
    cmds.window("SMG")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=20, value=4, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("SMG")

def createSniperUI():
    cmds.window("Sniper")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=2, value=2, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("Sniper")

def createRPGUI():
    cmds.window("RPG")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=1, value=1, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("RPG")


def printNewMenuItem(item):
    print item
    return item


def createUI(): 
    cmds.window("Bullet_Spray_Generator")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    GunSelectCtrl = cmds.optionMenu(label='Gun', changeCommand=printNewMenuItem)
    cmds.menuItem(label='Pistol')
    cmds.menuItem(label='Shotgun')
    cmds.menuItem(label='SMG')
    cmds.menuItem(label='Sniper Rifle')
    cmds.menuItem(label='RPG')

    cmds.button(label = "Continue", command = partial(createGunUI, GunSelectCtrl))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

createUI()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Dictionaries :

```
myDic = {}

myDic["anyString"] = "Value, String, Tuples,...etc"

print myDic
```

The good point of using dic is that you won't have to worry about nested variables.

To demonstrate the power of dictionnaries, I also add a function `createWeaponUI()`.

If you hit "Continue" with Shotgun selected, it will create a pistol/shotgun UI with createWeaponUI().
You just have to add `storedDataDic["weqponYouWant_preset"]` for each weapons at the top to generate whatever ui you want.
It is easier to read than 50 UI copy/pasted and use 50 if/elif to tell what weapon ui you should use.

Here is your modified script using dic:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

storedDataDic = {}
storedDataDic["weapon"] = ["Pistol", "Shotgun", "SMG", "Sniper Rifle", "RPG"]
storedDataDic["weaponSelected"] = storedDataDic["weapon"][0]
storedDataDic["Shotgun_preset"] = [(1,4,2), (1,50,25)]
storedDataDic["Pistol_preset"] = [(1,18,2), (1,25,10)]

if (cmds.window("Bullet_Spray_Generator", exists = True)): 
    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")
if (cmds.window("BSG2", exists = True)): 
    cmds.deleteUI("BSG2")

cmds.select(all=True)
cmds.delete()



def goShoot(numOfShots, distToTarget, *pArgs): 
    print "Begin"
    cmds.deleteUI("BSG2")
    createWall()

def cancelShoot(*pArgs):
    print "cancel"
    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")


def createWall():
    cmds.select(all=True)
    cmds.delete()
    wall = cmds.polyCube(h=10, w=15, d=1, name='wall')
    cmds.move(0,5,0, 'wall')


def createGunUI(gunType, *pArgs):
    if (gunType == 'Pistol'):
        createWeaponUI()
    elif (gunType == 'Shotgun'):
        createWeaponUI()
    elif (gunType == 'SMG'):
        createSMGUI()
    elif (gunType == 'Sniper Rifle'):
        createSniperUI()
    elif (gunType == 'RPG'):
        createRPGUI()
    else:
        print "Something went wrong"
        cancelShoot()



def createPistolUI():
    cmds.window("Pistol")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=9, value=4, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("Pistol")

def createShotgunUI():
    cmds.window("Shotgun")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=4, value=2, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("Shotgun")

def createSMGUI():
    cmds.window("SMG")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=20, value=4, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("SMG")

def createSniperUI():
    cmds.window("Sniper")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=2, value=2, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("Sniper")

def createRPGUI():
    cmds.window("RPG")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=1, value=1, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("RPG")


def printNewMenuItem(item):
    print item
    storedDataDic["weaponSelected"] = item
    return storedDataDic["weaponSelected"]

def ui_refreshSelWeapon(fun, *args):
    createGunUI(storedDataDic["weaponSelected"])

def createUI(): 
    cmds.window("Bullet_Spray_Generator")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    GunSelectCtrl = cmds.optionMenu(label='Gun', changeCommand=printNewMenuItem)
    for i in storedDataDic["weapon"]:
        cmds.menuItem(label=i)

    cmds.button(label = "Continue", command = ui_refreshSelWeapon)

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

createUI()



weapon_uiDic = {}

def createWeaponUI():

    weaponName = storedDataDic["weaponSelected"]

    if cmds.window(weaponName, exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI(weaponName)
    cmds.window(weaponName)
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")



    nbP= storedDataDic[weaponName + "_preset"][0]
    dcP = storedDataDic[weaponName + "_preset"][1]

    weapon_uiDic["NumBulletsCtrl"] = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=nbP[0], maxValue=nbP[1], value=nbP[2], field=True)

    weapon_uiDic["DistCtrl"] = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=dcP[0], maxValue=dcP[1], value=dcP[2], field=True)

    weapon_uiDic["fireButton"] = cmds.button(label = "Fire", 
                                            command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(weapon_uiDic["NumBulletsCtrl"], 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(weapon_uiDic["DistCtrl"], query=True, value=True)))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow(weaponName)
```

---EDIT---

> I had pistol preset to make it more clear

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to pass complex information around inside a GUI in Maya is to wrap the whole UI in python class. The class can 'remember' all of your fields, sliders, etc so that you can easily collect information from one or more GUI items and act on them without too much extra work.

```
class PistoUI(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.window =  cmds.window("Pistol")
        cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
        self.bullet_count = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots', minValue=1, maxValue=9, value=4, field=True)
        self.distance = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)',  minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)
        cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = self.fire)
        cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = self.cancel)
        cmds.showWindow(self.window)

    def fire(self, _ignore):
        bullets  =  cmds.intSliderGrp(self.bullet_count, q=True, v=True)
        distance = cmds.intSliderGrp(self.distance, q=True, v=True).
        goShoot(bullets, distance)

    def cancel(self, _ignore):
        cmds.deleteUI(self.window)
```

As you can see above, the `fire` function gets the correct fields from the active window and collects their values to pass to the goShoot function without any extra work in the layout step to pass the values directly to a function. This is much simpler and more elegant than leaving all the pieces lying around in the open. It's also more self-contained - you can create multiple windows side-by-side in that scheme without worrying about creating and deleting them by name.

Even better, the clases are really good for separating out differences in logic from difference in data, so you can resuse the repetitive code with ease:

```
class WeaponUI(object):
    LABEL = 'weapon_name'  #default name
    SHOTS = (1, 9, 4)   # default shots
    RANGE = (1, 50, 25)  # default range

    def __init__(self):
        self.window =  cmds.window(title = self.LABEL)
        cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)
        self.bullet_count = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots', minValue=self.SHOTS[0],
                                                    maxValue=self.SHOTS[1],
                                                    value=self.SHOTS[2], field=True)
        self.distance = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)',  
                                                    minValue=self.RANGE[0], 
                                                    maxValue=self.RANGE[1], 
                                                    value=self.RANGE[2], field=True)
        cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = self.fire)
        cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = self.cancel)
        cmds.showWindow(self.window)


    def fire(self, _ignore):
        bullets  =  cmds.intSliderGrp(self.bullet_count, q=True, v=True)
        distance = cmds.intSliderGrp(self.distance, q=True, v=True).
        print "firing", self.LABEL
        goShoot(bullets, target)

    def cancel(self, _ignore):
        cmds.deleteUI(self.window)

class PistolUI(WeaponUI):
    LABEL = 'pistol'  
    SHOTS = (1, 9, 4)   
    RANGE = (1, 50, 25) 

class ShotgunUI(WeaponUI):
    LABEL = 'shotgun'  
    SHOTS = (1, 4, 2)  
    RANGE = (1, 50, 25) 

class SniperUI(WeaponUI):
    LABEL = 'sniper'  
    SHOTS = (1, 4, 2)  
    RANGE = (1, 50, 25)
```

... and so on

More about maya GUI connections [here](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/04/maya-callbacks-cheat-sheet.html) and [here](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/02/rescuing-maya-gui-from-itself.html)

Comment: Best answer of em all. You beat me to it! When I looked at all the repeating and similar statements in the OP's code all I could hear is the Gods of Python going "DRY, DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)"! Why not unleash the power of classes objects and inheritance? Great answer.

Comment: You should mark the most helpful answer as accepted so future readers will be able to figure out what works

Comment: Classes are really the best way to go. But if you don't know about dictionnaries, you have a lot to learn about classes and inheritance :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it fails is `GunSelectCtrl` is an UI control which is the option menu created in `createUI` method. It is not a string. In `createGunUI` method, you treat `GunSelectCtrl` as a string, if statement will of course fail.

You need to use command `cmds.optionMenu(GunSelectCtrl, value=True, q=True)` to retrieve the string gun type.

Besides, there is an error when I run the script:

```
global name 'GunSelectCtrl' is not defined #
```

You need to define it as a global variable and declare it where it is used: methods `createUI` and `createGunUI`.

The modified code is below:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial


if (cmds.window("Bullet_Spray_Generator", exists = True)): 
    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")
if (cmds.window("BSG2", exists = True)): 
    cmds.deleteUI("BSG2")

cmds.select(all=True)
cmds.delete()

GunSelectCtrl = ""

def goShoot(numOfShots, distToTarget, *pArgs): 
    print "Begin"
    cmds.deleteUI("BSG2")
    createWall()

def cancelShoot(*pArgs):
    print "cancel"
    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")


def createWall():
    cmds.select(all=True)
    cmds.delete()
    wall = cmds.polyCube(h=10, w=15, d=1, name='wall')
    cmds.move(0,5,0, 'wall')


def createGunUI(gunType, *pArgs):
    global GunSelectCtrl
    gunType = cmds.optionMenu(GunSelectCtrl, value=True, q=True)

    if (gunType == 'Pistol'):
        createPistolUI()
    elif (gunType == 'Shotgun'):
        createShotgunUI()
    elif (gunType == 'SMG'):
        createSMGUI()
    elif (gunType == 'Sniper Rifle'):
        createSniperUI()
    elif (gunType == 'RPG'):
        createRPGUI()
    else:
        print "Something went wrong"
        cancelShoot()



def createPistolUI():
    cmds.window("Pistol")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=9, value=4, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("Pistol")

def createShotgunUI():
    cmds.window("Shotgun")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=4, value=2, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("Shotgun")

def createSMGUI():
    cmds.window("SMG")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=20, value=4, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("SMG")

def createSniperUI():
    cmds.window("Sniper")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=2, value=2, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("Sniper")

def createRPGUI():
    cmds.window("RPG")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    cmds.deleteUI("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

    NumBulletsCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Number of Shots',
    minValue=1, maxValue=1, value=1, field=True)

    DistCtrl = cmds.intSliderGrp(label='Distance to Target (metres)', 
    minValue=1, maxValue=50, value=25, field=True)

    cmds.button(label = "Fire", command = lambda *args: goShoot(cmds.intSliderGrp(NumBulletsCtrl, 
    query=True, value=True), cmds.intSliderGrp(DistCtrl, query=True, value=True), ))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("RPG")


def printNewMenuItem(item):
    print item
    return item


def createUI():
    global GunSelectCtrl
    cmds.window("Bullet_Spray_Generator")
    cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

    GunSelectCtrl = cmds.optionMenu(label='Gun', changeCommand=printNewMenuItem)
    cmds.menuItem(label='Pistol')
    cmds.menuItem(label='Shotgun')
    cmds.menuItem(label='SMG')
    cmds.menuItem(label='Sniper Rifle')
    cmds.menuItem(label='RPG')

    cmds.button(label = "Continue", command = partial(createGunUI, GunSelectCtrl))

    cmds.button(label = "Cancel", command = cancelShoot)

    cmds.showWindow("Bullet_Spray_Generator")

createUI()
```

Comment: I think it is bad habit to use "global" to declare ui variables. 
If you do this to multiple variables, it will be confusing.